# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) after running the SHOW route

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have two identical pages for my website working.ejs and show.ejs. Working.ejs is the default file to get render in the default route and it works perfectly fine.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render('working');   
});
```

[Working perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKBYf.png)

[image]

However, I get the error when running this route.

```
   app.get("/vids/:id", function(req, res){
       console.log(req.params.id);
       res.render('show', {name: req.params.id});
    });
```

[Error only appears after running the show route in my server script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39bY3.png)

[image]

Comment: Any relative paths will be relative to the `vids` directory for the `show` page.

Comment: THank you soo much guys. It worked. all i had to do was add a ../ to all of the links. Is there a way around that? I dont want to reroute all of my links and scripts